# How to get Querytables result to land on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pulling data from a site that limits the presentation of the data to 75 lines at a time, when some of the data sets contain 100 records
(Why is there never an option for ALL RECORDS)?

I could arrange my loop to just create a new sheet, but this would add more work 
since I would have to click through up to 50 sheets to join the sheets into one.

So far my script pulls the data, and I set a counter to offset the placement of the 
results so nothing gets overwritten. However, after the script completes I end up with 
in one case 1500 blank rows and then the last few rows of the dataset. So basically I get the last 75 rows or so (3 in one case) of 1000 element datasets
Not sure what I'm missing here. Does Querytables always place the link data in $A$1?

The code:

```
Sub getHistoricalData()
Dim sheetname As String, url As String
Dim x_wsnames As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet, destinationRange As Range
Dim fillRange As Range, cell As Range, startCell As Range, endCell As Range
Dim operationalRange As Range, max As Integer
Dim last_objid As Integer, m As Integer
Dim startPage As Boolean, divider As String
On Error Resume Next

For Each x_wsnames In Sheets("data").Range("B2:B11")
'url = x_wsnames.Offset(0, 2).Value
max = x_wsnames.Offset(0, 2).Value
sheetname = x_wsnames.Value
'  Sheets.Add.Name = sheetname
Sheets(sheetname).Select
  Set ws = Sheets(sheetname)
  Select Case sheetname
    Case "A"
         position = "one"
    Case "B"
        position = "two"
    Case "C"
        position = "three"
    Case "D"
    position = "four"
  Case "E"
    position = "five"
  Case "F"
    position = "six"
   Case "G"
    position = "seven"
  Case "H"
    position = "eight"
  Case "I"
    position = "nine"
  Case "J"
    position = "ten"
End Select
Debug.Print "Processing cycleThroughWorksheets() " & sheetname

m = 0
For i = 1 To max
   url = "http://dataplace/search?category=type&dataType=historical&locations=ALL&d-112233-w=" & i & "&filter=" & divider

'Debug.Print i, url
If i = 1 Then
    Set destinationRange = Range("$A$1")
    Debug.Print destinationRange.Address
Else
    m = m + 75
    Set destinationRange = Range("$A$" & m)
    Debug.Print destinationRange.Address
End If
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & url, destination:= _
    destinationRange)
    .Name = sheetname
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Next


Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what's the question asked here.

Comment: The answer is "no", the tables don't just get forced into A1.  I notice that with your 2nd table, it would actually start on row 75, when I think what you want is 76.  Have you stepped through to see if there are in fact individual tables being created.  If so, are they filling correctly?  I'm not sure what happens when you try to create contiguous tables with no separation.  It seems like they might merge or do something weird.

Comment: Alexandre, I am pulling web page info for several different pages and storing the result in one sheet.